# Hangfire Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I'm currently working on web application that require Content Security Policy to be implemented particularly the script-src part.  In this appliction i wanted to implement hangfire as a background task runner but faced a problem that it is well described here : https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/696 but without answer. So i wanted to ask people who are smarter than me :) is there some workaround for this issue that does not involve changing hangfire layout page or allowing script-src unsafe-inline ?

Comment: Interesting. It looks like you might need to make your own branch of Hangfire. You could clone the repo and modify your version of [this file](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/LayoutPage.cshtml). You would just take the contents of that script tag and move them to another file. The only tricky part might be figuring out exactly how the Hangfire dashboard serves script files, so you know where to move that code. You might even be able to submit the change and contribute to the repo, so you don't have to keep using your own branch.

Comment: Fix was included i hangfire 1.6.10 after my pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to upgrade Hangfire version in your application. version 1.7.25 has fixed this csp issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31488624)